# Assign specific template to specific pages

Tags: theming, 7

H i I am quite new in Drupal and have been trying to figure out a way to assign a specific template file to some specific pages following the taxonomy like **page--user--edit.tpl.php** works but I don't want to create a single template file for each page I require to change. I have been trying the following code but this doesn't work for me is there any cleaner way to achieve this in drupal 7

```
function phptemplate_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
 if (arg(0) == 'node' && (arg(1) == '10')) {
   $vars['template_files'][] = 'page-sometest';
 }
```

Comment: phptemplate_ prefix is dead as of Drupal7, see http://drupal.org/node/422116

Answer (score 10):

See here [Drupal 7 Theme Hook Suggestions](http://drupal.org/node/1089656)

For nodes You can use

> `node--[type|nodeid].tpl.php`
>
> `base template: node.tpl.php`
>
> Theme hook suggestions are made based on these factors,  listed from
>   the most specific template to the least.  Drupal will use the most
>   specific template it finds:
>
> `node--nodeid.tpl.php`
>
> `node--type.tpl.php`
>
> `node.tpl.php`

Also [Drupal 6 Template Suggestions](http://drupal.org/node/1089642)

To use same tpl for multiple pages you need to use theme_preprocess_node Like

```
function theme_preprocess_node(&$vars, $hook) {
  $node = $vars['node'];
  if(in_array($node->nid), $myuids)
   $vars['template_file'] = 'your_template_file';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Drupal way to do this is to create a specific template file for each page.  Trying to override the theme system in this manner will create a mess if your site grows larger and becomes more complex.

If you don't want to create a file per page, I would recommend learning how to use the [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) module.  It does take some time to learn, but Panels provides an interface that allows you to relatively easily customize the layouts to any node or groups of nodes (content types, etc.) on your site.  If you've never used Panels before, I recommend [Node One's introduction](http://dev.nodeone.se/node/770).

Comment: is there a reason why writing this function in template.php didn't work for me 
function phptemplate_preprocess_page(&$vars) { if (arg(0) == 'node' && (arg(1) == '10')) { $vars['template_files'][] = 'page-sometest'; }