# How to theme single node differently to nodes in taxonomy list?

Tags: theming

I'm editing node.tpl.php, to apply custom theming when the site displays single nodes.

However, if I browse for a certain taxonomy term, the list of nodes presented is also affected by my changes.

Is there a way to theme just the single node pages?

Comment: You can find answer here http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/29353/assign-specific-template-to-specific-pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have access to the `$page` variable in your template file; if the node is being displayed in a full page this variable will be `TRUE`, and `FALSE` otherwise.

If you look at the core [node.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.tpl.php/7) file you can see it too takes advantage of this:

```
<?php if (!$page): ?>
  <h2<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><a href="<?php print $node_url; ?>"><?php print $title; ?></a></h2>
<?php endif; ?>
```

That's used to only display a title on the node if it's *not* the main page display.

You also have access to a `$view_mode` variable if you want to be more specific about the particular view mode, e.g.:

```
<?php if ($view_mode == 'teaser'):
<?php // print something ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

See same question here. [Assign specific template to specific pages](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/29353/assign-specific-template-to-specific-pages)

See here [Drupal 7 Theme Hook Suggestions](http://drupal.org/node/1089656)

For nodes You can use

```
node--[type|nodeid].tpl.php
base template: node.tpl.php
Theme hook suggestions are made based on these factors,
```

listed from the most specific template to the least. 
Drupal will use the most specific template it finds:

```
node--nodeid.tpl.php
node--type.tpl.php
node.tpl.php
```

Also [Drupal 6 Template Suggestions](http://drupal.org/node/1089642)

To use same tpl for multiple pages you need to use theme_preprocess_node Like

function theme_preprocess_node(&$vars, $hook) {
  $node = $vars['node'];
  if(in_array($node->nid), $myuids)
   $vars['template_file'] = 'your_template_file';
}

Answer (score 0):

What version of Drupal? Take a look in the [Theming Guide](http://drupal.org/documentation/theme). Especially the [Overview of theme files](http://drupal.org/node/171194) and [Working with template suggestions](http://drupal.org/node/223440). In the last link, you can see, when you install [Theme Developer](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) how the template file has to be named.
The sum of all in D7: [Drupal 7 Theme Hook Suggestions](http://drupal.org/node/1089656)