# I want to change the layout of add/edit page

Tags: 7, theming

I have one content type called *Restaurant*, and I want to change the layout of this content type in the administrative area. When the administrator user adds/edits a Restaurant node, the layout should be my custom layout.

How can I change the whole layout?

Comment: See here http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/29353/assign-specific-template-to-specific-pages/29355#29355

Comment: thanx.. but This will work for display front side it is not work in admin area. i have try this "page--node--add--article.tpl.php" for add page it is working but "page--node--edit--article.tpl.php" it is not working. but "page--node--edit.tpl.php" it is working for all content edit page but i want to work only on article.

Comment: You ca check for arguments in that node page itself. like node/add/CONTENTTYPE etc.

Comment: sorry but it not work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown in the comment at the beginning of [theme_get_suggestions()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_get_suggestions/7), for a URL such as http://www.example.com/node/1/edit, the following default suggestions will be used.

- `page__node`
- `page__node__%`
- `page__node__1`
- `page__node__edit`

If you want to add `page__node__edit__article` as suggestion, you need to implement [hook_preprocess_page()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/7) in a module. The following code works for any content type.

```
function mymodule_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if (!empty($variables['node']) && arg(2) == 'edit') {
    // (1)
    array_unshift($variables['theme_hook_suggestions'], 'page__node__edit__' . str_replace(array("/", "\\", "\0", '-'), array('', '', '', '_'), $variables['node']->type));
    // (1)
  }
}
```

If you want to be use not to apply the template file for, e.g., node/1/edit/revert, replace the code between `// (1)` with the following one.

```
$arg3 = arg(3);
if (empty($arg3)) {
  array_unshift($variables['theme_hook_suggestions'], 'page__node__edit__' . str_replace(array("/", "\\", "\0", '-'), array('', '', '', '_'), $variables['node']->type));
}
```

Comment: Thanx kiamlaluno its work for me.