# Custom Add page

Tags: forms

I need to create a custom 'Add' and 'Edit' pages for specific content type, with some entity reference drill down behaviours.

I'm trying to override the add page like below with my form within it, maybe I am missing something major?

I have tried both of the below but none seem to do anything?

node--add--contenttype.tpl.php
page--node--add--contenttype.tpl.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [I want to change the layout of add/edit page](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33928/i-want-to-change-the-layout-of-add-edit-page)

Comment: With that method would I be able to load node data and reference other nodes behind the scenes? For example I need to create a drill down of drop down boxes like the Hierarchal select module but by entity references instead of taxonomy terms etc. I need to select a region then select a country then find all nodes within that county, things like this which can't be achieved from a  simple add form